# Item with fixed position not appearing in right place

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm trying to add page-to-top code to a page. Everything works fine except for the positioning of the "to top" button.

I've shown the problem in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/oe9fqv3p/). You can see the To Top in the lower right. I need it to be in the lower right of the middle div.

My code is below. I looked up the fixed position description and it says it aligns to the viewport. Is there a way to override that so it aligns to a specific div?

```css
.layout {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#toTop {
  padding: 5px 3px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="layout">Left column</div>

  <div class="layout">Middle column
    <span id="toTop">To Top</span>
  </div>

  <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could try use `position:sticky`, but you may need polyfills for some browsers

Answer (score 1):

You should add `position: relative;` to `.layout` and `position: absolute;` to `#toTop`. The absolute positioned element will have its relative parent as base

Comment: I tried all of the various options. Most worked as posted but, as mentioned, there are browser issues. I decided to use the code I posted. I had to change the offset command to position to get better control but it works in all browsers. My thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

```
.layout {float:left; width:150px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;position: relative;}

div > span { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oe9fqv3p/13/
This will do it for you.

I added the `relative` position and in the `div > span` positioned it `absolute` and `right 0` and `bottom 0`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed couple of styles in your CSS code. The example is here 
https://jsfiddle.net/2yms90qz/

Though i am not sure if you want something like this. Please let me know.

I have removed float from your divs and added inline-block as display. Also changed some position value to achieve the result.

```css
.layout {display: inline-block; width:150px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;}

.middle {
  position: relative
}

#toTop {
 /* padding: 5px 3px; */
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="layout">Left column</div>
 <div class="layout middle">Middle column
 <span id="toTop">To Top</span>
 </div>
 <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that "To Top" button **always visible on the bottom of the viewport**, then you would have to position it relative to the viewport in a way that it matches the location you want, relative to the parent.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.layout {
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.layout:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}

#totop {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  right: calc(35vw + 10px);
  outline: none;
}

#totop:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Left column</div>

  <div class="layout">Middle column
    <button id="totop">TO TOP</button>
  </div>

  <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Something else here.</div>
<div>
```

Note, however, that as you pointed out in your comment, this means the "To Top" would still be visible even when you scroll past that first `.container` element.

To avoid that, if you just want that button to be at the bottom of its column, even if that's outside of the viewport and the user needs to scroll down to get to it, then you should use `position: absolute` instead and also add `position: relative` to `.layout`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.layout {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.layout:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}

#totop {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

#totop:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Left column</div>

  <div class="layout">Middle column
    <button id="totop">TO TOP</button>
  </div>

  <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Something else here.</div>
<div>
```

To get the best of both worlds, and make the "To Top" button stay at the bottom of the viewport until the end of the first `.container` is reached, and remain inside it when the user scrolls past it, you could use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.layout {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.layout:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}

#totop {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  top: calc(100vh - 49px);
  float: right;
  outline: none;
}

#totop:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Left column</div>

  <div class="layout">Middle column
    <button id="totop">TO TOP</button>
  </div>

  <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Something else here.</div>
<div>
```

The only problem with this approach could be browser support.

In that case, if you really need this feature/behaviour, you could implement your own sticky element using JS and listening for the [`onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and ['onresize'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) events.

Alternatively, you can use JS to check if `position: fixed` is supported and apply one solution or another:

```js
const hasSticky = (() => {
  const el = document.createElement('div');

  el.style.cssText = "position:sticky;position:-webkit-sticky;position:-ms-sticky;";
  
 return el.style.cssText.indexOf('sticky')!==-1;
})();

if (hasSticky) {
  document.getElementById('totop').classList.add('sticky');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.layout {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.layout:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}

#totop {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

#totop.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: auto;
  top: calc(100vh - 49px);
  right: auto;
  float: right;
}

#totop:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Left column</div>

  <div class="layout">Middle column
    <button id="totop">TO TOP</button>
  </div>

  <div class="layout">Right column</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="layout">Something else here.</div>
<div>
```

Comment: It looks like your first example is what I need. I didn't think to show it in my code but there is more on the page below those div's. I update my jsfiddle to use your code. as you can see, when the page is scrolled, the To Top text goes outside of the middle box. This is not too big a problem on a desktop but on a mobile, the To Top appears all the way through all other content and that is a big problem. Is there a way to stop the scroll so it just displays in the middle div? Here's my updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/oe9fqv3p/24/

Comment: @user3052443 Please, take a look at the updated answer, that might be closer to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

**.layout should be positioned and .top should be absolute.**

```
.layout{
    position:relative;
 }
.top{
    position :absolute
 }
```

please see
https://jsfiddle.net/ainouss/39ezf0yj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the scroll code I was using to look for the last button on the page and to hide the To Top button when it reached it. Here is my updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/oe9fqv3p/46/) and code. The numbers are not quite correct but I'm just posting this in case someone else runs across this problem. I'm not sure if it is the best solution but I've tested it here and it seems to work fine. My tnaks to all who replied.

```
    <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 150vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .layout {float:left; width:150px;height:250px;border:1px solid red;}
    .layout-middle {position:relative;float:left; width:150px;height:250px;border:1px solid red;}

    #toTop {
      font-family: monospace;
      border: 3px solid red;
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 60px;
      z-index: 100;
      right: calc(45.33333333% + 10px);
      outline: none;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="layout">Left column</div>
     <div class="layout-middle">Middle column
     <span id="toTop">To Top</span>
     </div>
     <div class="layout">Right column</div>
    </div>
    <div><button id="button-isvisible">Button</button></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){

      var offset = 20;
      var duration = 500;
      $(window).scroll(function() {  

      var continue_button_pos = $('#button-isvisible').offset();

      var button_top = continue_button_pos.top - 350 ;
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > button_top) {
              $('#toTop').fadeOut(duration);
          } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
              $('#toTop').fadeIn(duration);
          } else {
              $('#toTop').fadeOut(duration);
          }
      });
    });  
    </script>
```